# Reading file until "EOF" encountered. How can I catch this?

Tags: java, file-io

I would highly appreciate it if anyone can point me in the right direction on this, please. I am reading a text file in using Scanner class. At the end of the data file, I have a "EOF" trailer. I would like to the while loop to stop as soon as "EOF" is encountered. My thoughts were to put "&&" statement within the while loop but throws a run-time error.

data.txt

```
January Feburary March
January Feburary March
January Feburary March
January Feburary March
January Feburary March
EOF EOF EOF
```

Code:

```
public class ReadFile {

    static Scanner input;
    static final int MAX_LEN = 50;
    static int counter = 0;
    static String filePath = "data.txt";
    static File file;
    static Records[] records;

    //METHOD: MAIN
    public static void main(String[] args){ 

       records = new Records[ MAX_LEN ];          

        try {
            file = new File( filePath );
            input = new Scanner( file );

            do{            
                records[counter] = new Records();
                records[counter].str1 = input.next();               
                records[counter].str2 = input.next();               
                records[counter].str3 = input.next();
                ++counter;
            }
            while(input.hasNextLine() && records[conter-1].str1 != "EOF");
            input.close();
        }
        catch ( IOException ex ){       
            System.out.println( "File access error" );  
            counter = 0;
        }//        
    }//MAIN
```

Comment: Just say when line is equal to end of line `EOF` stop looping by breaking out of it using `break`.

Answer (score 0):

`records[conter-1].str1 != "EOF"` will not work, try `!records[conter-1].str1.equals("EOF")`